# Data Binding Not Working On Dialog - why?

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android, and I try to get a detail of data from a recycleview. After you click an item from the list, it will show you the detail of that item. It works perfectly when I use normal method (R.findview) but when I use data binding, it doesn't show any detail on the dialog.

Pojo Class :

```
    public class DosenModel {
    private String nama;
    private String id;
    private String pelajaran;
    private String foto;

    @BindingAdapter("loadFotoDosen")
    public  static void loadImage(ImageView imageView, String imageUrl) {
        Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

This is how I initialized the data binding in the adapter

```
 public DosenAdapter.MyAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ListItemBinding listItemBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new MyAdapterViewHolder(listItemBinding);
}
```

How I try to show the dialog in the fragment

```
   private void detailDialog(DosenModel dosenModel){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity());
    Log.d("Dosen", dosenModel.toString());
    detailLayoutBinding.setDosen(dosenModel);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

The data from the adapter is saved in dosenmodel variable, and I already check the data using Log.d

Detail XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="dosen"
            type="example.com.cleancodetest.model.DosenModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
            android:text="DETAIL DOSEN"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:id="@+id/view_foto"
            android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
            app:loadFotoDosen="@{dosen.foto}"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view_id"
            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@={dosen.id}"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view_nama"
            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="@={dosen.nama}"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view_pelajaran"
            android:layout_marginStart="150dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="@={dosen.pelajaran}"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

If need more detail, feel free to ask.Thank you.

Comment: If i'm correct, you are not setting any data to dialog. Inside `detailDialog` method you are creating empty dialog, and setting variable to data binding. There is nowhere where you set data to dialog.

Comment: You can try to call `setView(detailLayoutBinding.getRoot())` on your dialog builder. That should work.

Comment: @SamirSpahic So I cant use `detailLayoutBinding.setDosen(dosenModel);` to set the data to the dialog?

Comment: @SamirSpahic Thank You, It Works!!

Comment: I will add this as an answer, so please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setView(detailLayoutBinding.getRoot())` on your dialog builder.